# Making updates using swr in Next js

Tags: reactjs, database, typescript, next.js, crud

I'm trying to make a component that has an active property, and it's supposed to be toggleable, so the user can switch to active or inactive as many times he or she wants. Since I'm using Next js, I decided to use SWR to render some pages on the client-side. It's my first time using it and I've been trying to implement this functionality for days and I wasn't able to get it done.

Every component receives the handleToggleActive function in a map method located in the parent component

here's the function

```
async function handleToggleActive(brtId: number) {
    const selectedBrt = data.response.find((brt) => brt.id === brtId);

    setBeingEdited(selectedBrt);

    setBeingEdited((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        active: !prevState.active,
      };
    });

    try {
      const body = {
        active: beingEdited.active,
        brtId,
      };

      const res = await fetch("/api/brainstorm/update", {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });

      if (res.ok) {
        mutate("/api/brainstorm/user-brainstorms");
      } else {
        alert("An error ocurred");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err.message);
    }
  }
```

Here's my edit: I noticed something in the function. As I told, every time I run the function, the current item being edited is inserted into the beingEdited state, and when the request ends, I set the state as null again. The update happens, but only if I press the switch twice, because it sets the state as null and then fills it with data for the next request. Is there a way to make it be toggled in one click?

Comment: Why is `setBeingEdited(...)` being called twice?

Comment: Because it starts as a null, since no item was selected to make the switch action.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the change here as it's easier than in comments.

instead of calling `setBeingEdited(...)` twice like that

I would change this...

```
const selectedBrt = data.response.find((brt) => brt.id === brtId);

    setBeingEdited(selectedBrt);

    setBeingEdited((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        active: !prevState.active,
      };
    });
```

To this...

```
const selectedBrt = data.response.find((brt) => brt.id === brtId);

     setBeingEdited({...selectedBrt, active: !prevState.active});
```